# MYSQL - having count(*) without group by

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have a MySQL table

```
discount_vouchers
------------------
id
email
test_id
```

My goal is to list all vouchers that appears more than once with a given email and a given test_id from the GROUP BY:

```
GROUP BY email, test_id
HAVING count(*) >1
```

How to get read of this group by?

Here is an example:

```
discount_vouchers
------------------
1    1@test.com    20
2    1@test.com    10
3    1@test.com    20
4    2@test.com    30
```

I would like to have as a result:

```
id     email     test_id   count
1    1@test.com    20       2
2    1@test.com    10       1
3    1@test.com    20       2
4    2@test.com    30       2
```

Comment: Try this `WHERE (SELECT count(*) FROM discount_vouchers GROUP BY email) >1 OR (SELECT count(*) FROM discount_vouchers GROUP BY test_id) >1`

Comment: @gamitg, this is not working and it will change the logic of the query.

Comment: What's wrong with a 'GROUP BY' ?? Also, I don't understand how your result set correlates with your data set.

Comment: @Strawberry: looks like OP wants the count results applied to each row of the ungrouped data. e.g. get grouped results without actually grouping

Comment: @MarcB I expect you're right - but the result set doesn't presently reflect that ambition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like the following

```
SELECT C2, counter from 
(SELECT C2, COUNT(*) as counter FROM test.mytable
GROUP BY C2) as aggregation
WHERE counter > 1
```

Without using group by, you can do something like

```
SELECT a.* , 
   (SELECT count(*) FROM discount_vouchers b 
    WHERE a.email = b.email AND a.test_id = b.test_id) as count
FROM discount_vouchers a
```

Comment: Hi dchar, could you please give more details here?

Comment: The inner query performs the group by and calculates how many times each value appears. You must assign the inner query an alias, in this example "aggregation". Then you have an outer query that is performed on the results of the inner query and selects only records with counter > 1.

Comment: In fact, this is not working as expected, I am still getting only the C2 with the Group BY ran, I need all C2 values, not only the grouped by

Comment: Can you please explain with an example? (maybe with a fiddle, this would help). The group by query should return you all the C2 values, as long as they exist at least once.

Comment: In fact, the query returns all the C2 values as long as they exist at least once, but the returned values are grouped by (two fields in my case). My goal is to have all the voucher_discount IDs, without the GROUP BY

Comment: I added an updated query, please check if this does what you want.

Comment: Thanks, how is the count > 1 checked in the 2nd query?

Comment: Basically you search for other rows with the same email and test_id, but with a different id. So the query will get you all voucher ids for which there are at least 2 rows with the same combination of  email,test_id.

Comment: In your example the last count should be 1, right? I updated the query so as to return the count, as per your example.

Answer (score -1):

How about this?
Aggregate using a subquery, and use its results in order to enrich the actual table:

```
SELECT `discount_vouchers`.*, `counts`.`count`
FROM   `discount_vouchers`
       INNER JOIN (SELECT `email`, `test_id`, Count(*) AS 'count' 
                   FROM   `discount_vouchers`) AS `counts` 
           ON `discount_vouchers`.`email` = `counts`.`email`
          AND `discount_vouchers`.`test_id` = `counts`.`test_id`;
```

Comment: Hi Nitai, this returns me only one result.

Comment: @Miloš - I must admit I have reviewed the query and I can't figure why would it fail. Could you add a test case to the question, or a sample of the data? I have node understood your request as it was intended.